# Does Angular cache the last working version of your system?

Tags: angularjs

I wish I could replicate this in a Fiddle or something but I can't in any easy way, so I'll just describe it.

I'm building an Angular app, and even when I make changes, things aren't changing in the browser. This tends to happen when my changes result in some errors. If I make lots of changes and there are no bugs, it works. But if I make another change with some broken piece of code, and refresh the browser, it goes back to something that worked before but isn't what my app looks like now.

Is this normal/expected?

Comment: Does *Angular* cache your project? No, and it doesn't make sense. How are you building? Deploying?

Comment: I'm just editing the code in webstorm and refreshing my browser as I go

Comment: how can anyone figure your issues out when you mention `'broken code` but give no clue what that means or what errors it causes?

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.x isn't a module loader, so it will not fetch any script from web server.

So, there's any way to Angular getting your system cached. It caches your templates, though, but only until next refresh.

It there's something caching your scripts on your development machine, look at your webserver. Also, your IDE may not deploy it while there are any syntax errors.